# Automating Android build process

Tags: java, android, process, build

I have to do a very laborious task on a regular basis and am looking for a way to automate the process.
I have to Clone 2 git repos, open in eclipse, add one repo as a dependency of the other,c hange package names, refactor, replace the res folder with another and build.
I want to write a script or something that will automate the whole process. Is this possible? If so where do I start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this possible?

Um, sure.

> If so where do I start?

I would start by choosing a programming language and toolchain for doing the work.

A slick solution would be to use Gradle with [the Gradle for Android plugin](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system), as it already knows how to do the build. "add one repo as a dependency of the other" can be done right from the `build.gradle` file. If your objective of "change package names, refactor, replace the res folder with another" is simply to have a different application ID (e.g., to allow it to be uploaded to the Play Store as a distinct app from others), Gradle for Android can do that just via `applicationId`, without any actual changes to the code itself.

However, you do not have to use Gradle. You are welcome to choose any other programming language, at least one that can run external commands to do the builds.

Answer (score 2):

Try **Jenkins** its a **continuous integration server**.It can even pull code from the github repo and produce android builds without having to go through the tedious manual steps

Hope this answers your question

Comment: Please explain how Jenkins will "add one repo as a dependency of the other, change package names, refactor, replace the res folder with another", since that is the bulk of the question.

Comment: @CommonsWare - I know the facts But not the inner details.